# How do you define the scope of a feature?

Tags: java, android, architecture, clean-architecture

I've currently been reading up on the [Clean architecture](http://fernandocejas.com/2015/07/18/architecting-android-the-evolution/) for Java/Android and I like the approach a lot.

Going through the articles, everyone gives a very good explanation of how your application should be structured from a high level perspective (Presentation/Domain/Data) and they all seem to recommend packaging by feature but I find the information regarding actual **directory structure** quite lacking.

For example, if we would take the classic TODO application:

[image: TODO application example]

How to I define the scope of the features? In which package do I place my base/core components such as f.e. executors?

Comment: This is a primarily opinion-based question. I don't think SO will be a good place to ask things like this. Have you tried going into software engineering forums?

Comment: Despite being opinion-based, I still believe that SO has a collective of clever minds that can all provide their insight/paradigm for this situation. Afterward it's just a matter of selecting the one that seems to work the best for my situation/approach. Sort of the same deal as with coding styles. (f.e. yes/no underscore before member variables, etc...)

Comment: True. It's just those minds often choose to follow the rules defined on the site. After all, those rules is what define SO in the first place. It's what set it apart from other resources out there. Just my two cents. I have nothing against you. Just trying to suggest so that you may achieve better chance at getting your question answered.